# How to write files to EFS from a docker image in ECS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I'm trying to create a docker image that does the following:

1.Create an EFS on AWS

```
RUN aws efs create-file-system --creation-token=$EFSNAME --performance-mode generalPurpose --throughput-mode bursting --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --tags Key=Name,Value=$EFSNAME;Key=Name2,Value=$EFSNAME
```

2. Generate some files inside the image.

   `touch sample.txt`
3. Write the files in into the newly created EFS.

The last step is what is confusing me. After reading the docs it wants me to mount the EFS, but isn't there some way to just directly populate my data into EFS? and if not what is the steps needed to populate EFS with that sample.txt

Comment: You will need to mount the EFS on the local  filesystem. There is no other interface to the service.

Comment: I don't think the procedure you describe involves Docker at all; it's definitely not something you'd do while building an image.

Comment: @DavidMaze it's not while building the image, it's while running the image. The image runs a script that will create the EFS and generate the files. My confusion is how do I populate the EFS with the files

Comment: @RodrigoM i need to mount the EFS on the local filesystem after I have created it? Remember that this is happening inside the container where the image is being ran